# React Native Firebase dynamic links send improperly via iMessage

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, imessage

React-native-firebase dynamic links send improperly via iMessage

I’m using `react-native-firebase/dynamic-links@11.3.3` to create a dynamic link for my app. Then I’m using `react-native-share@3.5.0` to give a user the possibility to send the link via communicator.

Link configuration:

```
         const link = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink(
            {
              link: `https://example.com/?some_id=${id}`,
              domainUriPrefix: 'https://example.page.link',
              android: {
                packageName: 'my.android.package',
                minimumVersion: '160',
              },
              ios: {
                bundleId: 'my.ios.bundle’',
                minimumVersion: '160',
                appStoreId: '000000000',
              },
            },
            dynamicLinks.ShortLinkType.UNGUESSABLE,
         );

         await Share.open({url: link});
```

It works via social media apps, Android’s Messaging and copying.
But when I send it via iMessage on iOS (tested on 14.4 and 14.5) it sometimes “switches” a link from `example.page.link` to `example.com`. And this link leads to a webpage, not to app.

When checked in debug mode, `example.page.link` yields [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAg2n.png).

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Add some prefix text before the link and share that. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

For enyone wondering, what was the solution - changing

```
await Share.open({url: link});
```

to

```
await Share.open({message: link});
```

fixed the problem.